# Has anyone created a debian package for phusion passenger (aka mod_rails) that doesn't depend on rubygems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, debian, passenger

As a company policy, rubygems isn't allowed on any of our production servers (which all run debian lenny).  All production software must be installed via apt.  There is a package for passenger (http://packages.debian.org/lenny-backports/libapache2-mod-passenger), but it depends on rubygems.  Before I try to try to hack my own package (probably based on the debian one), I thought I'd ask to see if anyone has already done it.

Comment: Just curious what the reasoning is behind this policy?

Comment: I assume that it is so that unknown or untrusted software (like gems) can't be installed.  However, I don't make the policies, I just have to work within them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tools to "convert" gem into debian package. I've personally used http://github.com/thwarted/gem2deb  .. However, since my target is a embedded device, i haven't packaged any rails stuff but what you are asking should be really basic stuff..

There's also a debian project which does "official" packages for debian from popular ruby gems.  See their site for more info: http://pkg-ruby-extras.alioth.debian.org/index.html

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to use the rubgems package, you should not use the passenger package either.

You probably don't want to install the rubygems package because you installed it manually already. Simply run `gem install passenger` and `passenger-install-apache2` and you're done.

If you need any libraries/dependencies installed, the passenger installer will let you know what it needs.

Comment: If the policy is not to install gems, you may as well stop developing Ruby applications.

Comment: I created my own passenger debian package that doesn't require gems or the rubygems package.  It runs my sinatra apps just fine.  I think I'll continue doing ruby web applications.

Comment: -1 for not caring about sys-admins and people who want to use standard tools maintain production environments. For more info: http://pkg-ruby-extras.alioth.debian.org/rubygems.html && http://pkg-ruby-extras.alioth.debian.org/upstream-devs.html